# MVC Views loaded outside web folder, where to put web.config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have a solution today where i load my views from outside my web folder with a custom view engine and it works fine as far as the views concerns, but a "normal" setup for views are

```
/Root   
   /Views
      /Controller
         Action.cshtml
      web.config
```

And this is the structure I'm using with the new solution as well, but it seems as the web.config in the Views-folder is not used, but not the web.config in the "default" Views-folder either, so all my globaly added namespaces cannot be found and all my views are forced to have "using" on every single page and that is irritating.

Does anyone know where i should put the web.config to make this work?

Do you need my View engine? I also use my own VirtualPathProvider and it seems to work so don't think that is the problem.

Comment: There is global web.config file that is located in the root directory that applied to the whole application (where you can define globally added namespaces). Another Web.config file is located within the View folder and is used for your .chtml files. IIS server uses these web.configs that overrides default config file on the web server. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Well, not really. I need to be able to override the default web.config depending on what path outside of the web-folder is used. Treat it like Areas where each Area have own web.config but is located outside the web-folder